# Изменять информацию раз в сутки

Tags: php, таймер

Нужно на странице, изменять информацию через определенный период времени, например, раз в сутки.

К примеру, есть три div'a, они скрыты через css, нужно каждый день, в 12 часов, делать один из div'ов видимым. на следующий день скрывать текущий div, и показывать другой.

Не знаю, чем такое даже реализовать. Скорее всего на php, т.к. js привязывается к фронту, а тут нужен независимый от перезагрузок страницы таймер

Comment: Кажется вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. php date, if else

Comment: А "независимый от перезагрузок страницы таймер" - это текущее время ;)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше это делать на JS. Например следующим образом:

```js
//Задаем дату от которой будет веститсь отсчет показов
var startDate = new Date(2016, 8, 1, 12)
var div = []
div[0] = document.getElementsByClassName('day1')[0]
div[1] = document.getElementsByClassName('day2')[0]
div[2] = document.getElementsByClassName('day3')[0]



function millisecondsToDays(milliseconds) {
  return Math.floor(milliseconds/1000/60/60/24)
}


function updateVisibility() {
  //Скрываем все элементы
  div.forEach(function(item) {
     item.style.display = 'none';
  })
  var now = new Date();
  //Открываем элемент, который должен быть показан сегодня
  div[millisecondsToDays(now - startDate) % div.length].style.display = 'block';
  //Рассчитываем время до следующего обновления
  var nextUpdate = Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 1, 12)
  //Ставим таймер на следующее обновление
  setTimeout(updateVisibility, nextUpdate - now)
}
updateVisibility();
```

```html
<div class="day1">1</div>
<div class="day2">2</div>
<div class="day3">3</div>
```

**Update:**
что бы показать все элементы, можно использовать подобную функцию

```
function showAll() {
  div.forEach(function(item) {
     item.style.display = 'block';
  })
}
```